# How to make a android view like apple iOS tag edit ?

Tags: android, sdk

I am a junior android programmer,

I have a project needs to be done a UI as shown below, but i have no idea to done this thing.

this view like iOS Text Field, can type a word and click enter can be a tag of list, 
I have tried many methods (like textView, TextEdit, ....), but have not been able to make.

Anyone can give me some tips thing?

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4945989/image.png

Comment: are you looking for rounded corner view?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are seeking. If it is the notion that a field can contain text and other things, see: https://plus.google.com/u/0/113735310430199015092/posts/WUd7GrfZfiZ